# Where is the User Profile Service in Sharepoint Foundation?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have installed Windows Server 2008 R2 & SharePoint Foundation 2010 in my machine. But I cannot find 'Forefront Identity Manager' in the Administrative Tools-> Services section. Due to that, I cannot activate my 'User profile Service' in SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Is there a resolution for this?

Answer (score 6):

There is no User Profile Service with SharePoint Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

You should **NEVER** start, stop, or modify any SharePoint services through the Services dialog; these should always be managed through Central Administration -> Services on Server. During the initial provisioning of the User Profile Service, the FIM services will be installed and provisioned. Build the User Profile Services Service Application, Start the User Profile Service on the applicable server, then start the User Profile Synchronization Service on the applicable server (this will provision the FIM services). Make sure you double-check all of the permissions, and service account configurations to make sure everything is correct before starting the UPS Sync service. If your service fails to start, or gets "stuck" on starting, 99.9% of the time you have permissions wrong.

Edit: As Mike pointed out, there is no UPS in SharePoint Foundation. I overlooked in your post that your environment was Foundation.